# Meaning of VACUUM output

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, vacuum

When I run `VACUUM` on a table it gives output like:

```
CPU 35.06s/175.00u sec elapsed 811.97 sec.
```

What does `CPU 35.06s/175.00u sec` mean?
`VACUUM` on a single table in my DB takes a very long time, it is important for me to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took 175 seconds of user-space CPU time and 35 seconds of system CPU time.

The remaining 600 seconds were probably spent either blocked on read IO, or sleeping due to the throttling implemented by vacuum_cost_delay and related settings.

On Unix-like systems, the system and user times are determined by `getrusage`.